# Jquery/Ajax - Get Picture and Youtube in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

So i'm back here again trying to figure out how to use HTML correct and can't get it to work correctly after been trying many hours with this.

Anyways, i'm trying to make so the picture and youtube trailer should be shown in the HTML and what I search for is something like this.

[image: I want like this]

Right now im searching to make something like the picture but to get picture to be shown and a player with the trailer

so basically I want it to look similar like picture number one and I have come so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Movies</title> 
</head> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script> 
function callAjax(input) 
{ 
var url = "http://localhost:1337/search/" + input; 

$.ajax({ 
type:'GET', 
url: url, 
success: function(data) 
{ 
console.log('SUCCESS'); 
$('#title').html("Title: " + data.title);
$('#release').html("Release: " + data.release);
$('#vote').html("Vote: " + data.vote);
$('#overview').html("Overview: " + data.overview);
$('#poster').html("Poster: " + data.poster);

},
error: function(request, status, err) 
{ 
console.log('ERROR'); 
} 
}); 
} 

$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#get-json').on('click', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 

var input = $('#data').val().trim(); 
callAjax(input); 
}); 

}); 

</script> 

<body> 
<center> 
<div> 
<input type="text" id="data" name="data" size="15" maxlength="120" /> 
<button type="submit" value="search" id="get-json">Search</button> 
</div> 

</center> 

<section> 
<div id="json-output"></div> 
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="release"></div>
<div id="vote"></div>
<div id="overview"></div>
<div id="poster" img src="data.poster" style="width:104px;height:142px;"></div>

</section> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Also forgot to say that i'm very new at this, never done HTML really before and been trying to figure out this for a while without a result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create placeholders for your JSON elements. At first write without that JSON a sample of HTML page that will look like you want. That page should have elements (for example `div`) for `title`, `release` and so on. Those elements should have its class or ids to be addressed (as it is already with `<div id="json-output">`)

You do not have to stringify your JSON. It is better to work JSON, since you can address its elements. For example, to set value into specific placeholder element you can use:

```
$('#title').html(data.title);
$('#relese').html(data.release);
$('#vote').html(data.vote);
```

Comment: This might be a silly question. but am I on the right way? `<div align="center">
Titel: 
</div>` but how do I rename the div so it knows like it should be title here etc. ?

Comment: @WeInThis You should not remame it. It should have `id`. For example, `<div id="title"></div>`. Then you can write to it as `$('#title').html("Title: " + data.title);`

Comment: Oh that was quite simple! How is it if I want to add a poster to be shown and youtube? If its simple thing to do? EDIT: Hmm, Should I remove now everything and start from a plain HTML?

Comment: @WeInThis At first I would start from writing in plain HTML (and maybe CSS) page as you want. Beside elemets for text it should have blocks for images and trailer... Once you will have needed structure you can fill (or generate) those elements by script.

Comment: Tried to add picture just to try it too see how it looked but didnt work and I added `<div id="poster" img src="data.poster" style="width:104px;height:142px;"></div>` but without results

Comment: @WeInThis `<img>` is a seprate tag. It can be insdie `div`: `<div id="poster"> <img src="data.poster" style="width:104px;height:142px;"></div>`. Also you cannot set `src=data.poster` in that way. It is attribute. It may be for example $('#poster img').attr('src', data.poster);

Comment: @WeInThis It may be hard simultaneosly work with desired structure and filling it from JSON. At first make html sample without addressing that `data`. Just put some example values to see that it is fine for you. Then it will be simple to write script that generates such html and proertly fill all attributes.

Comment: Hmm I dont get this quite right now, the last sentence. I was thinking more like Java right now, where I have `$('#poster').html("Poster: " + data.poster);` and then add it into `<div id="poster"> <img src="data.poster" style="width:104px;height:142px;"></div>` since we have src="data.poster" but I guess it doesn't work like that?

Comment: Oh, well. I was thinking more like to learn first how to make the poster and youtube so I don't have to do it again, or could it be like I have to do it another way later on? Or will it be the same code later on aswell ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93014/discussion-between-orest-hera-and-weinthis).

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` will return the contents of a JSON object as a string.  It will not parse your JSON object and return HTML.

You can create a simple list like this:

```
function(data){
 var $list = $('<ul>');

 $list.append('<li>Title: ' + data.title + '</li>');
 $list.append('<li>Release: ' + data.release + '</li>');
 $list.append('<li>Vote: ' + data.vote + '</li>');
 $list.append('<li>Overview: ' + data.overview + '</li>');

 $('#json-output').html($list);
}
```

Comment: So I can remove `$('#json-output').html(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\n')); ` and add what you recommended instead?

Comment: Good solution for organazing text items. However, it works if `$('ul')` is replaced by `$('<ul>')`

Comment: Yes you are correct @OrestHera, I have updated the example code.  WeInThis, that is correct.  You will need to customize the html a bit to get the exact output that you have in your screenshot, but this is a basic example.